# category subcategory loop in php pdo

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have 2 tables with structure and data as follows:

Table 1

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
      `category_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `category_name` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
      `status` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Disabled',
      PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

with data:

```
    INSERT INTO `category` (`category_id`, `category_name`, `status`) VALUES
    (1, 'Electronics', 'Enabled'),
    (2, 'Computers', 'Enabled'),
    (3, 'Cell Phones', 'Enabled'),
    (4, 'Video Games', 'Enabled');
```

Table 2

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcategory` (
      `subcategory_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `subcategory_name` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
      `category_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
      `status` varchar(8) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Disabled',
      PRIMARY KEY (`subcategory_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

with data:

```
    INSERT INTO `subcategory` (`subcategory_id`, `subcategory_name`, `category_id`, `status`) VALUES
    (1, 'LED', 1, 'Enabled'),
    (2, 'DVD Players', 1, 'Enabled'),
    (3, 'Tablet', 2, 'Enabled');
```

I have the following php pdo code:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'connstring.inc.php';
    $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT *, C.category_id
    FROM category C LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategory S
    ON C.category_id = S.category_id AND S.status = 'Enabled' 
    WHERE C.status = 'Enabled'
    ");
    $q->execute();   
    //$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

    $currentCategory = null;
    while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $categoryID = $row[category_id];
      $categoryName = $row[category_name];
      if ($categoryName != $currentCategory) {
        echo "<h2>".$categoryID.' '.$categoryName."</h2>";
        $currentCategory = $categoryName;
      }
      echo "<p>".$row['subcategory_id'].' '.$row['subcategory_name']."</p>"; 
    }
    ?>
```

Which produces category grouped output as:

```
 1 Electronics

           1 LED
           2 DVD Players
 2 Computers
            3 Tablet

 3 Cell Phones


 4 Video Games
```

The Electronics and Computers categories have sub-categories.

I need to generate html tags and css selectors as shown below:

```
    <li class='submenu border_t'>
    <div class=cat_bg>
    <a title='Electronics' href='#'><span>Electronics</SPAN></a>
    </div>

    <ul class='level2'>
    <li><a href="#">LED</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DVD Players</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>      

    <li class='submenu border_t'>
    <div class=cat_bg>
    <a title='Computers' href='#'><span>Computers</SPAN></a>
    </div>

    <ul class='level2'>
    <li><a href="#">Tablet</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>  

    <li class='submenu border_t'>
    <div class=cat_bg>
    <a title='Computers' href='#'><span>Cell Phones</SPAN></a>
    </div>

    <li class='submenu border_t'>
    <div class=cat_bg>
    <a title='Computers' href='#'><span>Video Games</SPAN></a>
    </div>

    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the code which I have written.

```
<?php
            include_once 'connstring.inc.php';
            //Get records from database
            $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT *, C.category_id
            FROM category C LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategory S
            ON C.category_id = S.category_id AND S.status = 'Enabled' 
            WHERE C.status = 'Enabled'
            ");
            $q->execute();   
            $currentCategory = null;
            ?>
            <div class='categoriesmenuFather ' id='nav-cat' style='display:block' >
            <div class='categories_list categoriesmenu '>
            <ul class='level1'>

            <?php
            while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            $categoryID = $row[category_id];
            $categoryName = $row[category_name];
            if ($categoryName != $currentCategory) 
            {
            ?>
            <li class='submenu border_t'>
            <div class=cat_bg>
            <a title='<?php echo $categoryName; ?>' href='products.php?catid=<?php echo $categoryID; ?>'><span><?php echo $categoryName; ?></SPAN></a>
            </div>
            <ul class='level2'>
            <?php
            $currentCategory = $categoryName;
              }
            ?>
            <!--BOF Sub-Category-->

            <li><a href="products.php?catid=<?php echo $categoryID.'&subcatid='.$row['subcategory_id']?>"><?php echo $row['subcategory_name']; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>  
            <!--EOF Sub-Category-->
            <?php
            }
            ?>

            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
```

The above code produces unexpected results. How can i get a result in the desired html format noted above using the query code. Help requested.

Comment: The data is not displaying correctly formatted. Is there anything to be added to my code so that the loop works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat quick and dirty.  But I think this is the basic idea of what you are looking.  During the loop, close the ul and li before starting the next category.  Then when you are done looping, you can always close the last set manually.

```
while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $categoryID = $row['category_id'];
    $categoryName = $row['category_name'];
    if ($categoryName != $currentCategory) {
        $currentCategory = $categoryName;

        //-- Make sure there is html first.
        if ($html) {
            //-- Close the UL from previous category
            if ($previous == true) {
                $html .= '</ul>';
            }
            //-- Close the LI from previous category
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        //-- Start new category
        $html .= '<li class="submenu border_t">';
        $html .= '  <div class=cat_bg>';
        $html .= '      <a title="'. $categoryName .'" href="#"><span>'. $categoryName .'</span></a>';
        $html .= '  </div>';
        if ($row['subcategory_name']) {
            $html .= '  <ul class="level2">';
            $previous = true;
        }
        else
            $previous = false;
    }

    //-- Add sub category
    if ($row['subcategory_name']) {
        $html .= ' <li><a href="#">'. $row['subcategory_name'] .'</a></li>';
    }
}
//-- Close the last category UL and LI
if ($html) {
    $html .= '  </ul>';
    $html .= '</li>';
}
echo $html;
```

One other side not, you probably want to order the results from your sql query so that the categories are together.  Otherwise, you could possibly split up the same category.

Edit: I changed the code one last time.  I had to set a flag, $previous, to determine whether or not to close the UL from last iteration of the loop.

Comment: In your code above only one subcategory is displayed in Electronics category. Rest are missing. Seems like loop not running properly. Only 1 sub-category displayed as in this image link:  http://i58.tinypic.com/1z6cjmp.png

Comment: I ran a test with my code and it is looping correctly.  I would say that your issue could be related to the data being returned from your sql statement.  Can you print the array by using print_r($row); in the while loop?  Just make sure the data is there.

Comment: Sorry, let me check one more thing.

Comment: Okay, I did miss the first subcategory being added. Since the first subcategory is in the same row of data as the category, you have to add the subcategory there.  I edited my code and that should give you what you are looking for.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ Rylonian Thank you...Almost there, except that those categories having no sub-category like cell phones, video games are displaying blank <ul class="level2">  </ul></li>

Comment: Okay, one last edit.  You can do the same check to make sure their is a subcategory name before adding the ul.  This could be cleaner if you looped through the categories and then looped through the subcategories instead of trying to do it all in one loop.  Either way, the code that is there should work for you.

Comment: @ Rylonian It is messed up now...Image of html generated with incorrect code marked:   http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=34dnec0&s=8#.U5tWNP5xOPI

Comment: lol, some days are better than others.  I updated my answer one last time.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"<li class='submenu border_t'><div class=cat_bg><a title='Electronics' href='#'><span>"` before `$categoryName` and `"</SPAN></a></div>"` after.

Then add `echo "<ul class='level2'>";` if subcategory has.

Then add `"<li><a href=\"#\">"` before `$row['subcategory_name']` and `"</a></li>"` after.

Add `echo "</ul>";` in the end of subcategory list if it was.

Then `echo "</li>";` in end of category.

Or simple using some template in other file/s with some special strings for variables.

Comment: Sorry, i did not get your point. I have provided the code which i have written above and is the same as what you have noted. The issue is with some tags inside the loop.